# DC current gain

Tags: batteries, current, amplifier, bias

Does this graph provide information about the current gain of a transistor?

[image]
(KTC3198)

Comment: *Does current gain has to do the what's on the graph?* This makes little sense, please correct the sentence.

Comment: The chart should look more [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9IS6.png). I set the bottom curve at \$1.5\:\mu\text{A}\$ and each curve above it is an integer multiple of that. In no way does the corner occur around 1.5 V, as your chart shows. No idea how they generated that thing. Pick any VCE voltage (like 6 V.) Then look upwards and find a curve you like -- that's the base current. Then find the curve's intersection with the vertical line at 6 V (in this case.) That translates to a collector current. Divide the collector current by the base current of the curve. That's beta.

Comment: So with the beta in mind, I decided to make a common emitter circuit with 6v as my Vcc. If my Vce = 0, then Vce will be 3volts or so, and 2ma will be my chosen Ic. According to my graph, my Ib will equal 7.5 to 8 mirco amps, right?

Comment: @RuqayyaSaleh I don't entirely follow. But if VCE=3 V (fixed) and you want exactly 2 mA as the collector current, you can just sweep the base current in the narrow range you selected from your chart and find the exact value. For example, in my case [look at this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okDRp.png) result. There you can see that the base current in this specific case is \$6.784\:\mu\text{A}\$ for a collector current of \$2\:\text{mA}\$, So the beta (taking into account the Early Effect) and the fact this is just a Spice model of a BJT, is 294.8.

Comment: @RuqayyaSaleh Now, you can see from that image that I specified BF=290. But the actual beta was higher. This is, in part, because of the Early Effect. If I remove the Early Effect from the modeling, then the calculated beta would be closer to the specified 290.